# Is it possible to update node in only one project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I have a big shared project that is setup with a really old version which is what is installed globally on my computer. I want to start a new project with `npx create-react-app` but in order to run this I need to update node. I know updating node globally will without a doubt cause breaking changes.
Ive found a couple websites that say running `npm install -D node@[versionNumber]` could accomplish what im trying to do. So I opened the directory of the project im trying to create and ran this (everything seemed like it worked) but when I checked `node -v` it was still the old version.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Maybe you want something like [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)?

Answer (score 3):

+1 For using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). I find it helpful to add an `.nvmrc` file in each project.

For example, in one project `.nvmrc` will have:

```
8
```

and another it will have:

```
14
```

Then you can run `nvm use` or `nvm install` once inside each project to get the correct nodejs version.